# KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(int, int) modifiers getting overwritten?

Tags: java, awt, keystroke

The following code "looks to me" like it should, upon encountering the CTRL mask, remove it (and it out), insert (or in) the ALT mask instead, and then make a new keystroke that has the ALT mask and does NOT have the CTRL mask. And indeed I have verified that "modifiers" is getting set correctly.

However what I'm actually getting back from the routine, when passed a keystroke with the CTRL mask in it, is a keystroke that has BOTH masks (CTRL and ALT) in it.

I used to be returning the method result directly, and tried adding in the intermediate step of "k2" when it seemed like something was getting overwritten, but that didn't help.

Thoughts on what's going wrong?

```
public KeyStroke getKeyStoredToSystem (KeyStroke k) {
  int modifiers = k.getModifiers();
  if ((modifiers & InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK) != 0) {
    modifiers &= ~InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK;
    modifiers |= InputEvent.ALT_DOWN_MASK;
    KeyStroke k2 = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(k.getKeyCode(), modifiers); 
    return k2; 
  } 
  else {
    return k; 
  }      
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `getKeyStoredToSystem` indeed returns both masks (CTRL and ALT). This is due to the legacy and deprecated `Event.CTRL_MASK` which is not removed. This is the method fixed:

```
public KeyStroke getKeyStoredToSystem(KeyStroke k) {
    int modifiers = k.getModifiers();
    // If modifiers contains CTRL_DOWN_MASK
    if ((modifiers & InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK) != 0) { 
        // Remove CTRL_DOWN_MASK
        modifiers &= ~InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK; 
        // Remove deprecated CTRL_MASK
        modifiers &= ~Event.CTRL_MASK;  
        // Add ALT_DOWN_MASK
        modifiers |= InputEvent.ALT_DOWN_MASK;
        return KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(k.getKeyCode(), modifiers);
    } else {
        return k;
    }
}
```

You can see the result in the test method:

```
@Test
public void mytest() throws KeyStoreException {
    KeyStroke ks = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl pressed Z");
    KeyStroke actual = getKeyStoredToSystem(ks);
    
    Assert.assertEquals(actual.toString(),"alt pressed Z");
}
```